# Having different display on different Sitecore item types

Tags: xslt, sitecore, ascx

Let's explain with my specific example :

I have 3 types(template) of news : new, external news, product release;

I want to display them on the home page in different manners.

For now I'm doing a simple in my xsl:

```
<xsl:variable name="upcoming" select="./item[sc:formatdate(sc:fld('End Date',.),'yyyyMMdd') >= sc:formatdate($now,'yyyyMMdd')" />
<xsl:for-each select="$upcoming">
   <div>
       <h2>
          <sc:text field="Name" />
       </h2>
       <p>
          <sc:text field="Description" />
       </p>
   </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Fist solution would be something like that (obviously i don't know the real syntax):

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="template = 'external news'">
      <!-- something -->
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

But better yet would be a more object oriented approach and have a make_body() function Bound to the item that i could call from my home page rendering.

Or does Sitecore have a way to do a rendering of an item that can displayed in any pages; a rendering handled by the items itself ?

What do you think ?

---

## Update

I think i was not clear enough:

I want in my home page a last news box:

```
<div class="last_news">
    <h2>Last News</h2>
    <!-- Loop Goes here -->
</div>
```

My different news types(new, external news, product release) have different appearances when they are listed in that box :

new:

```
<div class="news">
    <h2><!-- title --></h2>
    <p><!-- abridged text goes here --><p>
    <a href="##news url##">read more</a>
</div>
```

external news:

```
<div class="news external">
    <img src="##website logo##">
    <h2><!-- title --></h2>
    <p><!-- abridged text goes here --><p>
    <a href="##external url##">read more on www.<!-- site name --></a>
</div>
```

product release :

```
<div class="news product_release">
    <div class="float_left">
        <img src="##product logo##">
        <a href="##product url##">Download now</a>
        <a href="##product download url##">Download now</a>
    </div>
    <h2><!-- title --></h2>
    <p><!-- abridged text goes here --><p>
    <a href="##news url##">read more</a>
</div>
```

Each News types has it's own template with different fields

- new: title, abridged text, full text
- external news: title, abridged text, external url, website select box
- product release: title, abridged text, full text, product select box

I can make a sublayouts (.ascx) or renderings (.xslt) for each type but now i want to know **how to display those in my loop**.

Can i put an placeholder inside my loop and Sitecore will know that placeholder must be use by the current item ?

Comment: Are you looking to stick with XSLT (yuck!) or willing to switch to C# and use sublayouts (user controls) or compiled web controls?

Comment: You haven't provided the XML document that is being processed. If you do, I will show you a simple and elegant XSLT solution.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use C# and use sublayouts aswell. xsl would fit for simple solutions, but when things get more complicated you might want to switch to sublayouts / user controls.

Comment: looking a bit around it seems sublayouts do is the solution. Now i need to get the sublayout from the selected item and tell it to render my item ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just have a rendering (xslt) og sublayout (asp.net control) per template bound to the presentation of that template?

Instead of creating a "complex" if or switch to handle different templates, make one simple per template?

Eg. you'd have these asp.net controls:

- new.ascx
- external_news.ascx
- product_release.ascx

otherwise if you prefer using 1 xslt, because they have a lot of shared fields, you could use the

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

functionality. I think you'd write it something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@template='external news'">
   //do something specific for the 'external news' template
</xsl:template>
```

And then you just make one for each template. Warning I'm not 100% sure that @template='x' is the correct syntax.

I hope this helps.

Comment: your fist solution is what i'm looking for, but i cant seem to find how to output a bound sublayont in my for each.

Comment: But do you have different templates for each type? ie is there a template "external news", "product release" etc or only different master/branches?

If there are different templates, you just need to setup the layout for those templates (on the Standard Values subitem). Ie. having a layout (.aspx page) with a placeholder where you add sublayouts (.ascx) or renderings (.xslt). This is just standard Sitecore stuff.

If it's different Master/branches (ie the same template), then I'd recommend doing it as templates that inherit. Ie. make a "master" News template, with the other templates inherit.

Comment: Yes, i can make a sublayout (.ascx) or a rendering (.xslt) for each template. But i don't want to show **one** item but the last **10** added items. I don't know how to display those sublayouts inside a list of many items.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this depends entirely on what kind of content you are going to display.  You could put anything you want in a Rich text field and have it be unique to the Item.  This is by far the easiest solution and makes the most sense to me... but maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do.  But I'm fairly certain you don't want to do this in XSLT. (of course, I'm biased... I don't do anything in XSLT)

If I really had to make the rendering behave different depending on the template, I would make it a sublayout with code-behind.  It just doesn't make sense to put business logic in XSL.

It's also possible to dynamically add a sublayout to a placeholder.  After all, this is what Sitecore is doing on the back end...  So you could specify the particular sublayout depending what (random?) item you are displaying and set the datasource to your item.